# Calling Database.GetDbConnection() twice in a row causes a System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ado.net

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Bar>> GetFoo()
{
    using var connection = this.Database.GetDbConnection();         
    var bars = new List<Bar>();
    try{

        var cmd = new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandText = "select * from GetFoo()",
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
            Connection = connection as SqlConnection
        };
       
    
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();           
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            var bar = new Bar
            {
                Foo = (string) reader["FOO"],
            };
            bars.Add(bar);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //await connection.CloseAsync();
        //await connection.DisposeAsync();
    }

    return bars;
}
```

When running this method twice I get:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at line await connection.OpenAsync();

This is what I know:

> If EF creates the DbConnection object, then EF will ensure it is
> disposed when the DbContext is disposed. On the other hand, if some
> other code creates the DbConnection object and passes it to EF, then
> it is the responsibility of the other code to also dispose the
> connection appropriately.

So what am I doing wrong here? Is there any way to overcome this issue? Can this.Datbase.GetDbConnection() be called twice in the same instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said:

> If EF creates the DbConnection object, then EF will ensure it is disposed when the DbContext is disposed.

So when EF creates the connection, instead to explicitly dispose the connection you get from `this.Database.GetDbConnection()`, you can just take it and open/close it:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Bar>> GetFoo()
{
    var connection = this.Database.GetDbConnection();

    using var cmd = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = "select * from GetFoo()",
        CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
        Connection = connection
    };

    var bars = new List<Bar>();

    try
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            var bar = new Bar
            {
                Foo = (string)reader["FOO"],
            };
            bars.Add(bar);
        }

        return bars;
    }
    finally
    {
        await connection.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

This way you will not get a NullReferenceException and your connection will be handled correctly because every time you call `connection.CloseAwait()`, ADO.Net will release the connection to the connection pool, or close the connection if connection pooling is disabled ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection.close?view=net-6.0#remarks)).
Later EF will dispose the connection when the DbContext is disposed.

In addition, if your sql query is pretty standard, you can also replace `SqlCommand` with `DbCommand` and make your code provider-independent:

```
    using var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from GetFoo()";
    //you can remove this line, it's by default set to Text
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
```

Comment: Already tried with
`finally
    {
        await connection.CloseAsync();
        await connection.DisposeAsync();
    }`
Doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: Yep because you're still disposing the connection. It is enough to just close the connection without explicitly call .DisposeAsync();

Comment: Yes but by doing it shoulnd't do it any harm either. Anyway I try to remove it from code and it is still not working :(

Comment: Strange behaviour I'm unable to replicate. Are you sure you are not disposing the DbContext elsewhere between calls?

Comment: We fixed by removing the "using" keyword as you did in your example and it worked.